# How do do I play these parts on piano?

Tags: piano, notation

Here is a piece of music by Yanni which is arranged for Piano, how should I play the parts I've shown with a circle and what are they called in music? Do they have any special name or is it called a special technique? I myself think that the base-line should be played continuously (something like legato). Am I right?
[image: How to play the parts I have marked with a red circle?]

Comment: Agreed, that question covers the technique. As to the rest of this question: There is no special name for this technique; those are simply two bass voices played simultaneously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is that the dots in bass clef with downtails are held for the two beats. It *could* be done with pedalling, or just held on by the finger that plays each of those notes.